# 5-operation python calculator

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, calculator

here I am implementing a pretty simple calculator with 5 operations only.

Comment: isn't `i**(1/2) == x` should be `i**(1/2) >= x`. If so the other output is wrong as well.

Comment: Walk through your program line by line with pencil,paper and calculator.  Try printing stuff like calcs, comparisons, variables to see what is happening. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake - you have to make sure square root is integer and more than or equal to `x`, but not exactly `x` (see comment below):

```
if x > 1 and y > x:
    num_of_programs = [None] * (y + 1)

    for i in range(x):
        num_of_programs[i] = 0

    num_of_programs[x] = 1

    for i in range(x + 1, y + 1):
        num_of_programs[i] = 0
        if i % 2 == 0 and i // 2 >= x:
            num_of_programs[i] += num_of_programs[i // 2]
        if i % 3 == 0 and i // 3 >= x:
            num_of_programs[i] += num_of_programs[i // 3]
        if i - 5 >= x:
            num_of_programs[i] += num_of_programs[i - 5]
        if i - 7 >= x:
            num_of_programs[i] += num_of_programs[i - 7]
        # fix here!
        if i ** (1/2) - int(i ** (1/2)) == 0 and i ** (1/2) >= x:
            num_of_programs[i] += num_of_programs[int(i ** (1/2))]

    print(num_of_programs[y])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative "brute-force" solution using a recursive function:

```
def calc(number, target, program="", programs=None):
    if programs is None:
        programs = []
    if number == target:
        programs.append(program)
        return
    if number > target:
        return
    calc(number * 2, target, program + "A", programs)
    calc(number * 3, target, program + "B", programs)
    calc(number + 5, target, program + "C", programs)
    calc(number + 7, target, program + "D", programs)
    calc(number ** 2, target, program + "E", programs)
    return programs
```

Example calls:

```
>>> len(calc(2, 10))
0
>>> len(calc(3, 20))
5
>>> len(calc(5, 100))
34660
```

You can also inspect the actual programs leading to the target:

```
>>> calc(3, 20)
['ADD', 'CCD', 'CDC', 'DA', 'DCC']
```

- `A`: multiply the current number on screen by 2
- `B`: multiply the current number on screen by 3
- `C`: add 5 to the current number on screen
- `D`: add 7 to the current number on screen
- `E`: take the square of the current number on screen

Comment: OP is using Dynamic programming. Recursion, in this case, will be very inefficient (exponential complexity due to duplication of calculation)